# I am trying to deploythis app in heroku and it is not working What is wrong?

Tags: heroku

I am getting this code in the log

```
2019-10-22T23:09:36.638187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com request_id=70f60e73-bc5f-499e-acbd-a0e08bed5d06 fwd="71.201.83.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-22T23:09:38.102978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com request_id=19e5cbf2-7b37-4c59-94d6-2df4c850a8eb fwd="71.201.83.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-22T23:09:46.400999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com request_id=407d3137-1fb9-4145-b6e1-8611d3d5eb78 fwd="71.201.83.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-22T23:09:46.922086+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com request_id=1d143784-1e70-4a10-83c2-d770f26b08a8 fwd="71.201.83.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-22T23:10:55.624245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com request_id=71011b13-643c-4857-b130-d2f52460d216 fwd="71.201.83.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-22T23:10:56.595624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com request_id=507bec1e-3d4c-4bfe-9528-ea96a5b9c4b4 fwd="71.201.83.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: What do you mean with `this app`. What kind of languages, what is your configuration, add what you've done so far here to have more chance to get help.

Comment: This app is the project I am trying to deploy in heroku. The language is node.js. I do not know what you mean by configuration. I have had multiple different errors before and have solved all of them and this is the only one I am having trouble with. I have researched online about this code and doesn't help me and came here looking for someone's help!

Comment: @FazalQuadri -- there could be several causes of an R10. if you saw it just once or twice and then it went away this is (relatively) normal, check Heroku status for downtime. If it continues contact Heroku support

Comment: I am still getting app crashed error just no more R10. Do you have a solution for this error? @JasonFB

Comment: contact Heroku support